# line chart plotted area from one point to other point not connecting used sapui5 vizfram

Tags: sapui5

I am developing line chart graph, but some how plotted area not connecting each other as you can see in image (200 and 105 not making line) here i am using 
version 1.28.30

Comment: i am new here , please tell me how can i put line of code

Comment: Please include the images. Thank you.

Comment: How to give horizontal bar in vizframe line chart ? any idea.